# How Does Java Overriding Work

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I have a stupid confusion, when we override the parent class method then does this derived overridden method still hold the code of parent class method, or it is a new fresh method which we can define?

Comment: A little bit of reasoning could give you the answer.  If your method also included the code of the overridden parent class method, then there would be no need for super.foo().  Alternatively, there would be chaos if it did because you, the developer, would get no choice on whether an overridden methods super is called or not. But no, your method does not "hold" any code except the code you write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this article to get concept clear. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Generally we do when we want to extend the method of super class or to want to change the complete logic.

**For ex:** Super class have sorting method which use bubble sort.

In Derived class you want to take same method but want to implement quick sort. Then we do overriding.

**Second**

If you want to execute super class method first then your sub class overriden method logic then we use `super.methodname()`.

Last to point of your question If you override the method and not called super class method like `super.method()` then its not mean its fresh method. Its means I already explain the sort example.

Answer (score 1):

what happens is *exactly* what's written in the annotation.

you override the method and instead of running the parent code for the method, it runs the current class's code

Comment: ... if you do not explicitely call `super.method()`.