# Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 custom arrow pickup not returning my CustomArrow

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I would like the player to pickup the Custom Arrow not an normal arrow.
I think its something to do with an ItemStack is this possible to do in Minecraft 1.12.2?
My arrow class called CustomArrow:

```
package domain.items.objects;

import domain.entity.ECustomArrow;
import domain.register.RegisterItems;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArrow;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class LevitationArrow extends ItemArrow {
    public LevitationArrow(String Name) {
        this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.COMBAT);
        this.setRegistryName(Name);
        this.setUnlocalizedName(Name);
        RegisterItems.ITEMS.add(this);
    }

    public ECustomArrow makeTippedArrow(World world, ItemStack itemstack, EntityLivingBase shooter) {
        return new ECustomArrow(world, shooter);
    }

}
```

Arrow entity called ECustomArrow

```
package domain.entity;

import domain.Utils;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityArrow;
import net.minecraft.init.MobEffects;
import net.minecraft.potion.PotionEffect;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public abstract class ECustomArrow extends EntityArrow {

    public ECustomArrow(World worldIn, EntityLivingBase shooter) {
        super(worldIn);

    }


    @Override
    public void arrowHit(EntityLivingBase living) {
        super.arrowHit(living);
        if (living != shootingEntity) {
            living.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(MobEffects.***EFFECT NAME***, Utils.SECS2TICKS(10), 1));
        }
    }
}
```

In my main items class i got

```
...
public static ItemArrow customarrow;
...
customarrow = new CustomArrow("customarrow");
...
```

Comment: As per your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48489309/1663383) about arrows, you need to override `protected ItemStack getArrowStack()` in your arrow entity and return an item stack of your custom arrow type.

Comment: Could you provide an working example using my own provided code as i never got it working

Comment: In your ECustomArrow class, override `getArrowStack()` and return a new item stack.

Comment: Provide example code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672144/how-does-java-overriding-work

Comment: Provide example code

Comment: Think for yourself.

Comment: What you told me to do made it so i can not pick up the arrow

Comment: Quote,  *`In your ECustomArrow class, override getArrowStack() and return a new item stack. – Draco18s yesterday`* In your other question you were not using a custom arrow entity. Now you are. In the comments I said this as well: *`Extend EntityTippedArrow and override getArrowStack to return new ItemStack(Items.ARROW); – Draco18s Jan 28 at 21:38`*. You haven't done that.

Comment: Items.ARROW where do i get that from?

Comment: You don't want `Items.ARROW` (which is in the `net.minecraft.init` package). You want to return `YourItems.customarrow`. I don't know the name of your class or its package, you called it *`my main items class`*